# Stop generating questions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a quiz game. I have 10 questions but after answering all of it, it just keeps generating questions, so what I want to happen here is to just answer 10 questions and move to the score result on the next panel or scene.
Please help me.

```
public Question[] questions;
private static List<Question> unansweredQuestions;

private Question currentQuestion;

[SerializeField]
private Text questionText;

[SerializeField]
private Text trueAnswerText;

[SerializeField]
private Text falseAnswerText;

[SerializeField]
private Animator animator;

[SerializeField]
private float timeBetweenQuestions = 1;

void Start()
{
    if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
    {
        unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
    }

    SetCurrentQuestion ();


}

void SetCurrentQuestion() 
{
    int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range (0, unansweredQuestions.Count);
    currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions [randomQuestionIndex];

    questionText.text = currentQuestion.question;

    if (currentQuestion.isTrue) 
    {
        trueAnswerText.text = "CORRECT";
        falseAnswerText.text = "WRONG";
    }else
    {
        trueAnswerText.text = "WRONG";
        falseAnswerText.text = "CORRECT";

}
```

}

```
IEnumerator TransitionToNextQuestion()
{
    unansweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (timeBetweenQuestions);


    SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

}

public void UserSelectTrue()
{
    animator.SetTrigger ("True");
    if (currentQuestion.isTrue) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("CORRECT");
    } else 
    {
        Debug.Log ("WRONG");
    }

    StartCoroutine(TransitionToNextQuestion());
}

public void UserSelectFalse()
{
    animator.SetTrigger ("False");
    if (!currentQuestion.isTrue) 
    {
        Debug.Log ("CORRECT");
    } else 
    {
        Debug.Log ("WRONG");
    }

    StartCoroutine(TransitionToNextQuestion());
}
```

}

Comment: Im not sure the word "until" is the one you actually mean.. "until" is keep pouring water until the cup is full..

Comment: i mean if all the 10 questions is answered it will move to the next panel.

Comment: so what problem are you specifically having?

Comment: Did you write the code?

Comment: just remove the questions asked from the list of questions and move on when the list is empty?

Comment: My problem is that the game is keeps generating questions even if i answered all of it.

Comment: i tried this: if (unansweredQuestions == null) now it stops when i answered all of the questions but its says "Argument is out of range." i want it to move on to the next menu like score stats after i finished answering all of the questions

Answer (score 0):

Since your  StartCoroutine is not provided I only can assume that this what you wanted

```
IEnumerator TransitionToNextQuestion()
    {
        if(unansweredQuestions.Count > 0)
        {
            unansweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (timeBetweenQuestions);
            SceneManager.LoadSceneSceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
         } else
            //Move on
    }
```

Comment: My problem is that the game is keeps generating questions even if i answered all of it. is this the solution?

Comment: I already replaced my IEnumerator with this code but it its still going

Answer (score 0):

It's like every time you reset scene for next question you have empty list of unansweredQuestions and keep recreating it from question list.

```
private static List<Question> unansweredQuestions; 

...

void Start()
{
    if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
    {
        unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
    }

    SetCurrentQuestion ();

}
```

and for new question you do this:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
```

EDIT:
Changing this LoadScene() with SetCurrentQuestion(); should work fine

Comment: still not working but i tried this: if (unansweredQuestions == null) 

now it stops when i answered all of the questions but its says "Argument is out of range." i want it to move on to the next menu like score stats after i finished answering all of the questions

Comment: then try something like this:  
    `if(unansweredQuestions.Count > 0)
    SetCurrentQuestion();
    else
    moveToNextMenu();`

Comment: i got an error on the
`moveToNextMenu();`

here's my code










`void Start()
 {
  if (unansweredQuestions == null)
  {
   unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
  }

  SetCurrentQuestion(); 

 
 }`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it earlier. Put `if(unansweredQuesti‌​ons.Count > 0) SetCurrentQuestion()‌​; else moveToNextMenu();` instead of `SetCurrentQuestion();` mentioned in my answer and change `moveToNextMenu();` to whatever you need to move to next menu as I don't see code responsible for that in your question.

Comment: what should i put on the `moveToNextMenu();` or what code should i use to stop generating the questions and get the result to the next scene or panel?, sorry i'm a beginner.

Comment: It depends where is your next menu. 
Another scene - `SceneManager.LoadScene()`
same scene - you need to make it visible and hide current menu. Just by adding that if from previous comment you stop generating another question (delete `else moveToNextMenu();` and check) but you still need move to next menu

Comment: ugh i can't get it to work, can you please edit my whole code? or can we teamviewer so that you can see my work?